# How to Display the Html DOM Elements based on JSON response type HandleBars

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars template, I have a json which has a property of "displayType", based on that I need to show/hide the dom elements.

I listed down the comments in my DOM which needs to display when. So conditions are not working properly, and am new to this.

JSON Object:

```
{
  "menu": {
    "level1": [
      {
        "title": "level1 title1",
        "level2": [
          {
            "title": "level2 title 1",
            "displayType": "txtimgdesc",
            "level3": [
              {
                "title": "level3 title 1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "title": "level2 title 2",
            "displayType": "img",
            "level3": [
              {
                "title": "level3 title 2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "title": "level2 title 3",
            "displayType": "textimg",
            "level3": [
              {
                "title": "level3 title 3"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

HTML for Level3:

```
<ul class="nav-list list-inline container">
   {{#each ./level3}}
   <li class="list-section">
      <a href="#" class="">
         <!-- display Image only if the type is txtimgdesc or txtimg   or img  -->
         <img class="img-responsive {{showType ../displayType}}" src="">
         <!--    display header title only if the type is txtimgdesc -->    
         <span class="{{showType ../displayType}}">Header title</span>
         <!--    display title only if the type is txtimgdesc or txtimg -->    
         <span class="{{showType ../displayType}}">{{{title}}}</span>
      </a>
   </li>
   {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Register Helpers:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('showType', function(dType){
   var _ckType = (dType) ? dType.toLowerCase(): "", returnType="";  
   returnType = (_ckType == "img") ? "" : "hidden";
   returnType = (_ckType == "txtimgdesc") ? "" : "hidden";
   returnType = (_ckType == "txtimg") ? "" : "hidden";
   return returnType;  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to manipulate your data *before* it gets to the template. For example, each object in each "level3" array could have the following properties added to it: `showImage`, `showTitle`, and `showDescription`. This way, the messy logic for determining what is shown and what is hidden can stay in your code and your template can be left clean and simple with just some straight-forward `if` logic.

However, for the sake of exercise, I have arrived at a solution that uses a [Handlebars helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) method.

The task is to add a class to an element if the `../displayType` of our current context *does not belong* to some group of display types.

This appears to me to be very similar to an {{#if }} helper, except that we want to pass a value and a list. The helper will evaluate to `true` if the value is in the list. If the value is *not* in the list, the helper will evaluate to false and the {{else}} block will render. I have named my helper `contains`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('contains', function (options) {
    var list = (options.hash.list ? options.hash.list.split(',') : []);
    var value = (options.hash.value || '');

    if (list.indexOf(value) > -1) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
    else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

Note that I cannot pass an array as part of my [hash arguments](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#hash-arguments), so instead I am passing a comma-delimited string and it is the job of the helper to split this into an array.

Now, in order for your template to use my helper, it would have to be modified as follows:

```
<!-- display Image only if the type is txtimgdesc or txtimg   or img  -->
<img class="img-responsive {{#contains value=../displayType list="txtimgdesc,txtimg"}}{{else}}hidden{{/contains}}" src="">

<!--    display header title only if the type is txtimgdesc -->    
<span class="{{#contains value=../displayType list="txtimgdesc" }}{{else}}hidden{{/contains}}">Header title</span>

<!-- display title only if the type is txtimgdesc or txtimg --> 
<span class="{{#contains value=../displayType list="txtimgdesc,txtimg" }}{{else}}hidden{{/contains}}">{{title}}</span>
```

One thing I like about this approach is that it makes it easy to apply a class for the case when the `../displayType` *is* in the list.

Comment: It looks pretty neat, I will give a try now. Thanks alot